# python Selenium in Colab NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, google-colaboratory, webdriverwait

Hello I'm newbie of selenium.
and I got the problem. I want to scrap using XPATH and not working.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1320, 550)

exchange_link = "https://icodrops.com/category/ended-ico/"
driver.get(exchange_link)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
ico_links = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='all']//div[@id='ajaxc']")
```

But the result is this

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='all']//div[@id='ajaxc']"}(Session info: headless chrome=97.0.4692.71)

I don`t know why it cant be work.

I just did by XPath.

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlf1K.png)

my code link is [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UkBx8vLaSe8QNAaf-0Wsx-jkAATY0O2x/view?usp=sharing),

Scrap page is [this](https://icodrops.com/category/ended-ico/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a wait / delay.
You can use expected conditions to wait for that element presence.
As following:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=chrome_options)
driver.set_window_size(1320, 550)

exchange_link = "https://icodrops.com/category/ended-ico/"
driver.get(exchange_link)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3/a[@rel]")))
time.sleep(1)
ico_links= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h3/a[@rel]')
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply. but i have one more problem.
when i changed code as you recommended and there is TimeoutException error

TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:

Comment: I have updated the answer, it should be `presence_of_element_located` condition there rather than `visibility_of_element_located`. However this element is not exactly the "links". To exctract links you will have to make some more efforts.

Comment: thank you for helping me Prophet. you are really kind to me :*)
but still have problem with "links"

`ico_links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]")))`
i was searching selenium docs but i couldn't find any solution

Comment: What problem is there now?

Comment: still have  'TimeoutException: Message:'

Comment: Well, I see no elements matching `/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/main[1]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a[1]` xpath locator there. Also, I didn't mention this locator in my answer so it seems to be a new, additional issue?

Comment: Really? idk why no elements matching because i followed xpath by Chopath
![image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yx5Y-ifbpNyzMfXB4V3kL_sQKHPCZTb3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Such long absolute xpaths are extremely fragile. What element are you trying to locate now?

Comment: i was tring to gather links. is there any way that i can do ?

Comment: i even tried short xpath as this ''//*[@id="ajaxc"]/div/div/div[*]/a''
but same error as before :((((

Comment: I have updated the answer with locator to get the links. I hope now the issue is resolved?

Comment: sorry for bothering you. but nothing changed . still same error with "//h3/a[@rel]" this

Comment: that's strange. Try changing back from `visibility_of_element_located` to `presence_of_element_located`. I see 100 items initially loaded matching this lovator. Scrolling will give you more elements

Comment: hmm that's strange too. for me it is not, even if i changed as `presence_of_element_located` and put wait time as 60

Comment: maybe you incorrectly copied the locator I wrote here?

Comment: the code you updated is what you using?
because i cant find any different

Comment: Yup, but I did not actually run it. I have no way to do that, but don't worry, I know Selenium good enough :)

Comment: yes i truly believe you are good enogh.
if it is comfortable for us. could you come to the link 
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UkBx8vLaSe8QNAaf-0Wsx-jkAATY0O2x/view?usp=sharing) and run it?

Comment: I have to go. We can continue next evening or later

Comment: no problem thanks a lot